# maven fail in spring project build trying to establish connection with database

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot, docker

i make a docker-compose and dockerfile for my spring project, but it fail on maven build stage becouse is trying to establish a connection with the postgres service, I have no idea how I could solve it.

this is my docker-compose file:

```
version: '3'
services:

  postgres:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: docker/postgres/Dockerfile
    restart: always
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: ${postgres_database}
      POSTGRES_USER: ${postgres_username}
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: ${postgres_password}
    ports:
      - '5432:5432'
    volumes:
      - ./pgdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data

  api:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: docker/jdk/Dockerfile
    restart: always
    environment:
      postgres_database: ${postgres_database}
      postgres_username: ${postgres_username}
      postgres_password: ${postgres_password}
    ports:
      - '8100:8080'
    depends_on:
      - postgres
```

my postgres dockerfile:

```
FROM postgres:11-alpine

ENV POSTGRES_DB: ${POSTGRES_DB}
ENV POSTGRES_USER: ${POSTGRES_USER}
ENV POSTGRES_PASSWORD: ${POSTGRES_PASSWORD}

COPY ./docker/postgres/init.sql /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d

EXPOSE 5432
```

my jdk dockerfile where i made the project build (it fails) and run the jar:

```
FROM maven:3.6.0-jdk-11-slim AS build

COPY ./src /usr/src/app/src
COPY ./pom.xml /usr/src/app

RUN mvn -f /usr/src/app/pom.xml clean package

FROM adoptopenjdk/openjdk11:jre11u-alpine-nightly

COPY --from=build /src/usr/src/app/target/logger_service-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar /usr/src/app/app.jar

EXPOSE 8080

ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "/usr/app/app.jar"]
```

error log:

```
[ERROR] Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 14.844 s <<< FAILURE! - in cl.getcolors.loggerservice.LoggerServiceApplicationTests
[ERROR] contextLoads(cl.getcolors.loggerservice.LoggerServiceApplicationTests)  Time elapsed: 0.014 s  <<< ERROR!
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Unable to open JDBC Connection for DDL execution
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Unable to open JDBC Connection for DDL execution
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Unable to open JDBC Connection for DDL execution
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: The connection attempt failed.
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: postgres
```

how can i fix it?

Comment: I think depends_on only determines the order that containers start in. The thing you want is a link: https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#links

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I have found the solution, maven tries to execute the tests of the application so it executes the call to the database based on the configuration, this happens with the mvn clean package command.
-DskipTests must be added the instruction to the command to run maven no tests, so you can build correctly.

```
mvn clean package -DskipTests
```

my dockerfile now look like this and work perfectly:

```
FROM maven:3.6.0-jdk-11-slim AS build

COPY ./src /usr/src/app/src
COPY ./pom.xml /usr/src/app

RUN mvn -f /usr/src/app/pom.xml clean package -DskipTests

FROM adoptopenjdk/openjdk11:jre11u-alpine-nightly

COPY --from=build /src/usr/src/app/target/logger_service-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar /usr/src/app/app.jar

EXPOSE 8080

ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "/usr/app/app.jar"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding further to the above explanation , it must be noted that while building the image there is no access to the database . Only once the containers are created do the programs have access to the database .