# Getting: "CommunicationsException: Communications link failure" errors while connecting to a MySQL Docker container

Tags: spring-boot, docker, maven, docker-compose

*pom.xml*:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.0</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>j1</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>j1</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
        <frontend-src-dir>${project.basedir}/src/main/frontend</frontend-src-dir>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-j</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.33</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.30</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>copy-react-build</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy-resources</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${project.build.outputDirectory}/static</outputDirectory>
                            <resources>
                                <resource>
                                    <directory>${frontend-src-dir}/build</directory>
                                    <filtering>false</filtering>
                                </resource>
                            </resources>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

*Dockerfile*:

```
FROM maven:3.8.5-eclipse-temurin-17-alpine
WORKDIR app
COPY src src
COPY pom.xml pom.xml
RUN mvn clean package
EXPOSE 8080
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "target/j1-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar"]
```

*docker-compose.yaml*:

```
version: "3.7"
services:
  springapp:
    build: .
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    networks:
      - spring-j0-net
    environment:
      - spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://mysqldb:3306/webdev_simplified?allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true
    depends_on:
      - mysqldb
    volumes:
      - ~/.m2:/root/.m2

  mysqldb:
    image: "mysql:8.0"
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    networks:
      - spring-j0-net
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: webdev_simplified
      MYSQL_USER: www_data
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: *** (changed, there is real password)
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: *** (changed, there is real password)
networks:
  spring-j0-net:
```

but after it downloaded all maven dependencies and after tests, I got:

```
#0 45.15  :: Spring Boot ::                (v3.2.0)
#0 45.16 
#0 45.25 2023-11-25T21:29:59.403Z  INFO 78 --- [           main] com.example.j1.J1ApplicationTests        : Starting J1ApplicationTests using Java 17.0.3 with PID 78 (started by root in /app)
#0 45.25 2023-11-25T21:29:59.406Z  INFO 78 --- [           main] com.example.j1.J1ApplicationTests        : No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
#0 46.36 2023-11-25T21:30:00.475Z  INFO 78 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
#0 46.46 2023-11-25T21:30:00.564Z  INFO 78 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 75 ms. Found 1 JPA repository interface.
#0 47.06 2023-11-25T21:30:01.254Z  INFO 78 --- [           main] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]
#0 47.16 2023-11-25T21:30:01.352Z  INFO 78 --- [           main] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 6.3.1.Final
#0 47.26 2023-11-25T21:30:01.411Z  INFO 78 --- [           main] o.h.c.internal.RegionFactoryInitiator    : HHH000026: Second-level cache disabled
#0 47.66 2023-11-25T21:30:01.822Z  INFO 78 --- [           main] o.s.o.j.p.SpringPersistenceUnitInfo      : No LoadTimeWeaver setup: ignoring JPA class transformer
#0 47.76 2023-11-25T21:30:01.889Z  INFO 78 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
#0 48.96 2023-11-25T21:30:03.070Z ERROR 78 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : HikariPool-1 - Exception during pool initialization.
#0 48.96 
#0 48.96 com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure
#0 48.96 
#0 48.96 The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
#0 48.96    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:175) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
#0 48.96    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:64) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
#0 48.96    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:825) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
...
```

The problem is clearly mysql. Locally it is running:

```
 mysql.service - MySQL Community Server
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mysql.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Sat 2023-11-25 15:14:45 CET; 7h ago
   Main PID: 669 (mysqld)
     Status: "Server is operational"
      Tasks: 46 (limit: 8140)
     Memory: 30.2M
        CPU: 2min 44.788s
     CGroup: /system.slice/mysql.service
             └─669 /usr/sbin/mysqld
```

But I guess it cannot create it in the docker? In docker-compose.yaml the ports are mapped from host to docker with the same port 3306. So where is the problem?

PS:
I was creating the Dockerfile and docker-compose.yaml file from https://medium.com/thefreshwrites/the-way-of-dockerize-a-spring-boot-and-mysql-application-with-docker-compose-de2fc03c6a42 and changed my `spring.datasource.url` to:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/webdev_simplified
```

instead of

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://mysqldb:3306/webdev_simplified?allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true
```

since mysql locally runs on `localhost:3306` not `mysqldb:3306`. But still didnt help (getting the same `Communications link failure` error)

PS:
here is the source code:
https://github.com/shepherd123456/springapp/

Bottom line:
Why is tests trying to connect do mysql at all (which is not yet initialized)?

Comment: Observations, not related to the issue: (1) Since the app and db container are on the same network, they can communicate over it - no need to forward DB port to the host. (2) You could make use of a [Multi-Stage build](https://docs.docker.com/build/building/multi-stage/) to cut down the final size of the Docker image for your app.

Comment: Does `mvn package` run full-system tests that depend on connecting to a running database?  That won't work in a Dockerfile; run these tests in your host development environment, before you `docker build` an image.  Also see for example [maven fail in spring project build trying to establish connection with database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55226062/maven-fail-in-spring-project-build-trying-to-establish-connection-with-database).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, it would be really helpful if you shared the full project. I suspect it looks somewhat similar to this one:

https://github.com/amilairoshan/SpringBoot-MySql-With-Docker-Compose

I successfully cloned it and fired it up by running:

```bash
docker-compose up
```

The errors you observed were due to MySQL still performing database initialization while the app attempted to connect to it.

After a few seconds, once the database fully initializes, the errors disappear.

This behavior is documented on the MySQL DockerHub [page](https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql):

> ### No connections until MySQL init completes
>
> If there is no initialized database when the container starts, a default database will be created. While this is expected behavior, it means that the container will not accept incoming connections until the initialization completes. This may cause issues when using automation tools, such as Docker Compose, which start several containers simultaneously.
>
> If the application you're trying to connect to MySQL does not handle MySQL downtime or waiting for MySQL to start gracefully, putting a connect-retry loop before the service starts might be necessary. For an example of such an implementation in the official images, see WordPress or Bonita.

I was able to successfully navigate to http://localhost:8080/all and fetch a sample JSON response once the JDBC errors went away.

---

### Edit

Upon clarification from the OP (he provided the repository link), the issue appears to be related to the build process, specifically in setting up a database connection to a test database instance.

A quick fix is to delete `src/test` since there are no tests to run and thus avoid any potential test setup. You could also alter the build script in your Dockerfile by changing:

```dockerfile
RUN mvn clean package
```

to

```dockerfile
RUN mvn clean package -DskipTests=true
```

Comment: I also cloned the repo and it worked. This is strange. So I assume my problem must be in source then. So here it is https://github.com/shepherd123456/springapp/

Comment: @milanHrabos Aha! You're suffering from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77549832/getting-communicationsexception-communications-link-failure-errors-while-con/77550117#comment136716086_77549832) issue.

Comment: But why? Why is tests trying to connect do mysql at all (which is not yet initialized)? I did not touched test from downloading spring boot boilerplate from https://start.spring.io/. So I have only `@SpringBootTest
class J1ApplicationTests {

 @Test
 void contextLoads() {
 }

}` this test I dont see any mysql context

Comment: I am not a Spring expert by any stretch of the imagination. ^^